# Not able to load csv file stored in aws s3 on html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have csv and html file in same s3 bucket, to access this I used cloudFront and mapped it to this bucket.
Now , I want to load this csv data in html but its not showing anything.
My cloudfront url can access both files but its not load and nothing showing.
here is my code:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"https://cloudfronturl/inventory.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    alert("Here's lots of data, just a string: " + data);
    var isv_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<isv_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = isv_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
            }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#isv_details').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ISV Details</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">ISV Details</h1>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="isv_details">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in console or network tab?

Comment: No error, infact its showing in network response csv data but nothing is displaying on UI

Comment: This error is showing Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of favicon.ico 403 (), though this file is not calling in my code and also , it is showing for cloudfronturl/favicon.ico, so i dont think its related

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved , it was due to bug in chrom where it is try to find some favicon.io which is not exist and it was resolved by adding:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
```